# Alternative word or phrase to "result" in computer jargon

Tags: single-word-requests, computing

I'm looking for a title to add in an Instructions file to explain what is obtained after running a script. The exact word in Spanish is "resultado" but in English "result" sounds too Spanish to me (maybe I'm wrong). I don't know if beyond being the right word, there's another word more used in computer jargon.

The reason I ask the question is that I can't find another word beyond *result*, but my analysis is from a literary point of view, not a computer one, so I may be missing something.

*End*, *obtaining*, *consequence* are not adequate terms I think.

Comment: Is this just a single-word title? How are you using the word you want? Do have a look at [our help for this sort of question](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it, each SE site has its own rules and I didn't know this specific one from this site. I edited the title.

Comment: We get a lot of request questions. Please see the checklist at the end of the linked help.

Comment: Thanks, the question is updated.

Comment: *Result* may be Latin, but it's a very common word in English: *Looking for a results-oriented, driven, and modest sales executive*.

Comment: I'm just one practitioner, but my default name for a function's return value is, in fact, "result"

Comment: Can you clarify why "result" isn't acceptable beyond it having a similar (and, in my experience, functionally identical) word in Spanish? In both languages I would choose "result" over "output" as I feel the latter is *more* jargony.

Comment: You say "maybe I'm wrong", and I think that yes, you are wrong here. "result" is a perfectly normal English word to use in a situation like you describe; the fact that it's similar to the Spanish word has no bearing on that.

Comment: Result is fine, 'response' also works.

Comment: Result is fine, so it output.  The former is more 'literary'.

Comment: "sounds too Spanish to me" gave me a chuckle, as I've felt a similar feeling going the other way.  "Lider" sounds way too much like an American faking Spanish to be a proper translation of "leader".

Comment: Ok, it's not a contest between languages, what I meant is about the meaning, not the word. There are several almost identical words in English and Spanish that have different meanings in certain contexts, especially technical ones.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The result of running a computer script is its ***output***

Defined in [TechTerms.com](https://techterms.com/definition/output) as:

> Data generated by a computer is referred to as output. This includes data produced at a software level, such as the result of a calculation, or at a physical level, such as a printed document. A basic example of software output is a calculator program that produces the result of a mathematical operation. A more complex example is the results produced by a search engine, which compares keywords to millions of pages in its Web page index.

Comment: According to this source ([codingninjas](https://www.codingninjas.com/blog/2018/12/08/difference-between-a-programming-language-and-a-scripting-language/)),  "output" is a term applied to results from programming languages.

Comment: @LPH - Programming languages themselves cannot produce outputs.  Programming languages are used to encode instructions for a computer to follow to execute a task which produces some output.

Comment: That is what I meant, but "output" is used only in connection with the encoding of instructions in programming languages in that source.

Comment: @LPH  OP asks about the results of running a script.  What do you think the script contains?

Comment: Instructions to accomplish a task that otherwise is done manually (for instance move a file to a given place if some conditions are satisfied).

Comment: @LPH Yes, and those instructions are encoded using a programming language.  In a similar way your boss may send you an email written in English to relay the steps he wants you to take to produce a report.   Your task is to write a report. The email (script) was written in English and your output after executing his instructions is the report.

Comment: @LPH The site you link to is not defining "output", it's just using that to refer to the result of a program that has been coded in a language. The fact that it doesn't use it in the "scripting language" column doesn't mean it doesn't produce output, they just used different wording there. And that site doesn't seem to be authoritative to me, it's just one person's writing style.

Comment: @LPH I read through that codingninjas article, and my assessment is that about a third of it is correct, about a third of it is incorrect, and about a third of it is too vague to be evaluated as correct or incorrect. The article is definitely not a reliable source and should not be cited as proof of anything.

Comment: -1 This is the definition of "output", as stated throughout the cited text. The word "result" can also be used like "return value", which has nothing to do with output.

Comment: @rexkogitans If your software doesn't output (return) your return value to somewhere (a file, a display for someone to read, to other software/other parts of the same software to use, etc.) then it's not actually a return value.

Comment: @user3067860 putting a return value in a specific register wouldn't really be considered "output", but it is definitely a return value

Comment: @Esther If you have a function that _puts data out_ onto a register, sure it is the output of the function. If you were coordinating with someone else who was calling your function you would need to agree on a contract of what input they would give you and what output you would give them back. It wouldn't necessarily be the output of the whole program, and you might use language-specific terms to describe it (parameters and return value, e.g.), but in a generic sense it is definitely output.

Comment: Speaking as a PhD in CS, the result of executing a program could be a side effect, like deleting a file or changing a register, whereas the output is specifically a result that creates a stream of data

Answer (score 3):

**Return value** could also be used in some contexts, though it is usually used "inside" a program and might be confused with **return code**.

**Printout** is another.

Comment: I think ‘return value’ is only used for a single value, so it could be used for e.g. an integer [exit status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status), but not a file or block of text.

Comment: I think "return value" is narrower than "result", so for example the result of an SQL query is not a return value.

Comment: Printout is a thing of the previous century

Answer (score 1):

A standard term for this is **expected results**. It is especially common regarding for test cases (often along with the term **actual results**). It would also be clear in the context OP’s scenario.

> Expected Result is an ideal result that the tester should get after the test case is performed. It’s usually documented together with the test case. It’s usually compared with actual result, and if the actual result differs from the expected one, the difference is documented and called a bug.
> — https://testmatick.com/software-testing-glossary/expected-result/

PS. Piggybacking on the answer from @jim “expected output” and “actual output” would also work too.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we employ these terms when using an *operational semantics* for the program. We would say

- The **result** of the execution of a program is the change to the machine state, which can include writing to memory, changing the file system, etc.
- An **output** is a result comprised of a data stream, which may be

  - written to a file (an **output file**), which may be ephemeral (**standard output**, *stdout*);
  - drawn on the screen (in a **window** or a **dialog box**); or
  - transmitted to another process (a **message**).
- An **artifact** is an output that is permanently recorded.

If we were using a *denotational semantics* — you aren't, I think, since your example is running a script — then the mathematical object denoted by the program execution would be a **result**.

Answer (score 0):

A common way of describing a computer program is as follows:

- Precondition,
- Input,
- Process,
- Output,
- Postcondition.

In a general way, *result* can include both the *output* (written to a message stream) and the *postcondition* (a change in the state of the program or some part of its environment).

There is a huge amount of published material on “how to write use cases”. However, for a simple script, the best example will often be another script in the same computing environment. After all, the goal of documentation is to communicate with other human beings, and every group of people has its favorite ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I would have used the word 'outcome'.

Comment: You should include the reasons why you think your choice is the best.